# How to fix transaction mistakes in CiviEvent & CiviContribute

Tags: civievent, civicontribute, database

In CiviEvent, had a user that mistook chargeback for refund then using the Line Item Edit extension made more mistakes. The result is that for one event payee shows $500 refund more than correct. Upon looking at the transaction history I can see what happened but there is no user interaction to edit this area. Reading some other threads by Joe Murray states these are listed in two tables `civicrm_entity_financial_trxn`and `civicrm_financial_trxn` but it's not clear to me how to clear these entries.

He did say that any refunds or adjustments to registration activity should be done in CiviEvent and not CiviContribute. There should me a huge neon red banner that says that on the page or some restriction control on the contribution page with a notation to make any edits in the event. (See image)

[image: CiviContribute transaction history example]

Comment: The above appears to say they registered & wound up fully refunded - can't you just start anew & add a new registration with the correct entries?

Comment: Thanks, Eileen. I considered that but then the Transaction ID will not match up with the original at the payment processor. Despite this, I think there should be a way for the SysAdmin to make corrections when staff make mistakes much like how mistakes get corrected at a cash register machine or POS kiosk; even if it has to be done at the database table level.